# Split String using flutter

Tags: string, flutter, dart, split

So I'm trying to split a string which contains operator.

Here is the example :

```
var string= "12+13+45-78*45/91=100"

(how can i achieve this using dart)
var result = [12,+,13,+,45,-,78,*,45,/,91,=,100]
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: What datatype do you expect the operators to be in that list? The output you expect is impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with something like:

```
RegExp exp = new RegExp(r"\d+|\+|-|\*|/|=");
String str = "12+13+45-78*45/91=100";
Iterable<Match> matches = exp.allMatches(str);
var list = matches.map((m) => (m.group(0)));
print(list);
```

it will print:

```
(12, +, 13, +, 45, -, 78, *, 45, /, 91, =, 100)
```

Comment: You may also want to show how to parse the numbers in the output to `int`s as that's what the OP's intended output implies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegExp for this:

```
void main() {
  final regex = RegExp(r"(?<=\+|-|\*|/|=)|(?=\+|-|\*|/|=)");
  final str = "12+13+45-78*45/91=100";
  final splitList = str.split(regex);
}
```